# Graphic novel that takes place in New York City involving a subway token

Tags: story-identification, comics

I know that area really narrows it down by a lot, since barely anything happens in NYC, but this was a black and white book.  It involves the search for some item (I think it was a subway token?) and it needed to be given to some evil spirits.  I know one of the villains of the book was a man who worked a lot with neon lights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[City of Light, City of Dark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/293099.City_of_Light_City_of_Dark)*

[image]

> Two kids fight to save their city from eternal winter in this gripping fantasy by Newbery Medalist Avi, illustrated by three-time Sibert honouree Brian Floca.
>
> The Kurbs give people light and warmth to establish a city, on one condition: The people must return the Power every year or risk losing the city — forever. This system works for centuries until evil Mr. Underton tries to steal the Power. If he succeeds, the Kurbs will take back the City, reducing it to a dark and frozen tundra. It's up to Carlos and Sarah to find the Power — housed in a subway token — and keep the City safe, despite secrets of Sarah's history that are entwined with the token. What ensues is a race against darkness. A race against the lies of the past. And most of all, a race against time

Found by searching for *graphic novel subway token evil spirits neon*

Comment: That's it, thank you!